# Retrieving multiple values from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have saved values retrieved from a database in java to an arraylist.
I have used a class to save the data to the array list as shown below.

```
    ArrayList<NewSms> details = new ArrayList<NewSms>();
    try{
        Statement query = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = query.executeQuery("Select `senderAddress,message,linkid from sdp_smsincoming where status=0 AND smsServiceActivationNumber =1234 ");`

        while(result.next()){
            String address = result.getString("senderAddress");
            String message = result.getString("message");
            String linkid = result.getString("linkid");

            NewSms smsdetails = new NewSms();
            smsdetails.set_address(address);
            smsdetails.set_message(message);
            smsdetails.set_linkid(linkid);
            details.add(smsdetails);;
        }
    }
```

However i now want to retrieve the values individually per row,from another class in the program.How can i do this?By individually i mean getting the address,message and linkid per row in the arraylist.

Comment: How can you identify a row? You can use HashMap<IDENTIFIER_TYPE, NewSms> and get from map by some identifier.

Comment: Now you have the details arrayList.. Just return it from the function and use an iterator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However i now want to retrieve the values individually per row,from another class in the program.How can i do this?

You just access each `NewSms` in the list. To access one by index, you could use:

```
NewSms sms = details.get(2); // Or whatever
// Now access the properties of sms
```

Or to access each of them in turn, use an enhanced for loop:

```
for (NewSms sms : details) {
    // Now access the properties of sms
}
```

Note that to comply with Java naming conventions, your `NewSms` class should have methods such as `getAddress`, `setAddress` - not `set_address`.

Also note that you need to close your result set / statement / connection - if you're using Java 7, you can use a try-with-resources statement; otherwise you should use `finally` blocks.

EDIT: If your problem is actually just returning the list, that's easy:

```
public List<NewSms> loadSmsDetails() {
    // Code as before...

    return details;
}
```

Then just call it from your other class:

```
// Where repository is a reference to an instance of the class containing the above method
List<NewSms> allDetails = repository.loadSmsDetails();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jon,but am to retrieve the vallues in a different class,details would not work here.More like a method returns the arraylist above.so when i call the method form another class,how do i retrieve the values in the arraylist?using details cannot work here.

Comment: @mungaihkamau: Well yes, you'd need to make this method return the `ArrayList`. If your question was actually about how you return a list from one method, it would have been helpful if you'd said so. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(NewSms smsdetails:details){ 
String address = smsdetails.get_address();
String message = smsdetails.get_message();
String linkId = smsdetails.get_linkid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However i now want to retrieve the values individually per row,from
>   another class in the program

You need to pass the arraylist to the another class and iterate over it there to get the individual elements. The idea is to use a common araylist - to store the values from the resultset and in another class to iterate through them.